# How to check if structs are initialised or not

Tags: c

```
typedef struct dict_pair {
  void *key;
  void *value;
  struct dict_pair *head;
  struct dict_pair *tail;
} dict;

dict* NewDictionary(void) {
  dict *dictionary = malloc(sizeof(dict_pair));
  dictionary->head = null;
  dictionary->tail = null;
}

int main(void) {
  dict *dictionary = NewDictionary();
}
```

I had initially planned to set the structs as null but the compiler does not allow it. How can I check if a struct is assigned or not?

Also, can I refer recursively declare the same struct inside the struct?

Comment: Use `NULL` instead of `null`. `null` isn't part of C.

Comment: write it as an answer, I wanna give you props for it.

Comment: Wait... so the problem is that "null" was not recognized? then yes, the  answer is use "NULL" instead. Or 0, if NULL happens to not be defined in your dev environment, which is rare these days but still possible.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It seems like your NewDictionary() function already NULLs out your head and tail pointers. Isn't checking those enough?

Comment: Aside from the fact that "null" won't compile, of course...

Comment: @nubela - I just wrote a lot of things as an answer. I hope they help.

Comment: @nubela . just a suggestion. Do not accept the first answer you look at, give people the time to write a more coomprehensive answer.
Just being rewarded for having been the fastest to answer is not going to improve the overall quality of SO answers.

Comment: I tend to leave my tab open :) Refresh it every so often. Given the props to chris :)

@Chris: Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C doesn't have `null`, it has `NULL`. So try this:

```
dict* NewDictionary(void) {
  return calloc(sizeof(dict)); 
}
```

This fixes a few problems:

1. You were leaving `value` and `key` uninitialized, so they could hold random garbage. Using `calloc()` will initialize everything to 0, which in pointer context is `NULL`. It won't even take that much more processing time.
2. You weren't returning anything. This is undefined behavior. If you function ends without a `return` statement, it's only by sheer luck that anything will be returned.
3. You were using `dict_pair` instead of `struct dict_pair`. In C++, `struct` names are in the regular type namespace, i.e. `t x = { 0 };` is valid C++, but in C you'd need to say `struct t x = { 0 };`.
4. You weren't checking the return value of `malloc()` (now `calloc()` but same rules apply). If there isn't enough memory, `calloc()` returns `NULL`. I'd hate to dereference a `NULL` pointer on accident. We don't have to check the return value here because I've done away with all the intermediate steps - `calloc()` is enough for us.

Note that `calloc()` is slightly less portable. Even though the standard does require that `void *p = 0` sets the pointer to a null pointer, it doesn't require that the null pointer be "all bits set to zero", which is what `calloc()` technically does. If you don't want to use `calloc()` for this reason, here's a version that does the same thing with `malloc()`:

```
dict* NewDictionary(void) {
  dict *dictionary = malloc(sizeof(dict)); 
  if(dictionary) {
    dictionary->head  = NULL;
    dictionary->tail  = NULL;
    dictionary->value = NULL;
    dictionary->key   = NULL;
  }
  return dictionary;
}
```

Or:

```
dict* NewDictionary(void) {
  dict *dictionary = malloc(sizeof(dict)); 
  if(dictionary == NULL) return NULL;
  dictionary->head  = NULL;
  dictionary->tail  = NULL;
  dictionary->value = NULL;
  dictionary->key   = NULL;
  return dictionary;
}
```

See how much nicer the `calloc()` version is?

As to your second question:

> Also, can I refer recursively declare the same struct inside the struct?

No, you can't do this:

```
struct t {
  struct t x;
}
```

But you *can* do this (which is what you're doing, and what you want):

```
struct t {
  struct t *x;
}
```

You can have a *pointer* to a `struct` inside the `struct` itself, but you can't have the actual `struct` inside the `struct` itself. What you're doing is perfectly legal, because you're using pointers.

Comment: The `calloc` version might be nicer, but it's technically not portable.  It sets the underlying representation of the pointers to all-bits-zero, but that's *not* necessarily the same thing as `NULL` (even though the value `0` when converted to a pointer compares equal to the null pointer).  (Not that I'm aware of any place where all-bits-zero pointers aren't equal to `NULL`, but something to bear in mind).

Comment: @caf - I was just made aware of that point. I've checked and, though I thought the wording was just "calloc sets stuff to zero" it does specify "all bits zero" which means that, yes, I do believe this super-edge-case is valid.

Comment: Yes, it's worded that way because it's not reasonable for implementation to know how you're going to treat the returned memory.  The same applies to using `calloc` to allocate floating point values - all-bits-zero is not necessarily `0.0f`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider calloc rather than malloc.

calloc fills the memory it allocates with 0s, so you'll have your head and tail as NULL w/o explicit assignment.

Comment: calloc() set memory to all-bits-zero, such that if you looked at the RAM with a magnifying glass you would see "00000000…".  This is fine for integers, but does not at all mean you'll get floating-point zeros or null pointers.

Comment: @sgm - That's tricky. I know `void *p = 0;` _is_ identical to a null pointer by the standard, but I don't know about `calloc()` because it says "all-bits zero" rather than just "assigned to zero."

Comment: @Chris: casting `0` to `void*` might involve conversions, so it's indeed true that a pointer with bit representation `0` (as returned by `calloc()`) isn't guaranteed to be a null pointer

Comment: If you dig through some museums, you may find a machine where 0 address is not same as NULL, but I doubt even that. Same applies to floating point numbers, even more so, as there is a standard for those. For all practical purposes, calloc does what it's expected to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a statically allocated variable for initialization:

```
dict* NewDictionary(void) {
  static dict null_dict; // no initializer, so zero by default
  dict *dictionary = malloc(sizeof *dictionary);
  *dictionary = null_dict;
  return dictionary;
}
```

This guarantees that member are correctly zeroed, regardless whether they're pointers, floating point or integer types.

Answer (score 0):

You can set them as `NULL`, but not as `null`. C is case-sensitive, and the `NULL` constant is all caps.

And to answer your second question, yes, `struct` definitions can be recursive in a sense. The internal reference has to be a pointer to the `struct`, instead of a straight definition of the `struct`. If the latter was allowed, you would end up with an infinitely recursing `struct` definition, which would be a bad thing. See Chris Lutz's answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a trick which is working for me.

```
struct hello{
    ....;
    ....;
    ....;
};

struct hello *t;

t=malloc(sizeof(struct hello));
free(t);
t=NULL;
```

Now u can easily check if `t` is initialized or not. And there is no memory leak at all.